# Uniformly continuous on a isolated point set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

Supposse $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^{n}}$ is an isolated point set, $\textit{i.e}$, $\forall x \in \Omega, \exists \delta \gt 0: \forall \epsilon \gt 0, B_{\epsilon}(x) \backslash \{x\} = \emptyset$. We know for a fact that a function $f$ is continuous on every isolated point, and since the $\Omega$ has only isolated points, $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$. My question is: is $f$ uniformly continuous in $\Omega$?

I thought of something but I almost sure that it is wrong:

Let $D = \{||x_{k+1}-x_{k}||, x_{k} \in \Omega\}$ be the set of distance between two consecutive points of $\Omega$. Since every point of $\Omega$ is an isolated one, zero is a lower bound of $D$, hence, the infimum of $D$ is well defined.

Let $\delta_{0} = \inf D$. Then $\forall x,y \in \Omega, ||x-x|| \lt \delta_{0} \implies 0=||f(x)-f(x)|| \lt \epsilon, \forall \epsilon \gt 0$, hence $f$ is uniformly continuous.

But then $\delta_{0}$ is dependent of an arbitrary point of $\Omega$, which contradicts the definition of uniformly continuity.

What do you think? Can $f$ be uniformly continuous in this set?

Comment: First, $\delta_0$ may be zero.  Second, let $\Omega=\mathbb N$ and $f$ be the square function.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The square function (or any other function) **is** uniformly continuous on $\mathbb N$; for each $\varepsilon>0$, just take $\delta=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is wrong. Why should we have $\delta_0>0$?

And, no, $f$ doesn't have to be uniformly continuous. Take, for instance $D=\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ and $f\colon D\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f\left(\frac1n\right)=n$. Assuming that we are dealing with the usual distance in $\mathbb R$ (and in $D$), $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Is D with usual distanse equivalent with discrete metric ?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: So every function on D is uniformly continuous. What is wrong? Why f on D is not uniformly continuous with usual distance?

Comment: Are you sure you want to talk about $D$? Not about $\Omega$?

Comment: I think that every continuous function on D is uniformly continuous because usual distance on D is equivalent to discrete metric.  But why in your answer f is not uniformly continuous? I can't find my mistake.

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $\Omega$, not $D$.